# UserControl inherited from a base custom UserControl does not have the default size

Tags: winforms, inheritance, user-controls, size

I've got a strange problem...

I have a UserControl inherited from another custom base UserControl and the default size that I set in my UserControl are not maintained when the control renders. What is strange is that if I remove the inheritance (my UC inherits directly from UserControl), the rendered size is correct!

My inherited control is loaded into a panel at run-time.

```
panel.Controls.Add(new ucLanguageSelection());
```

These are my controls:

```
public partial class ucBaseControl : UserControl
{
    public ucBaseControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public virtual void Reset()
    {
    }

    public new virtual void Update()
    {
    }

}

public partial class ucLanguageSelection : ucBaseControl
{
    public ucLanguageSelection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce.  My uc inherits from uc test worked fine.

Comment: Hi! Try to compile your code on a pc and execute on another with smaller resolution (eg. 1920x1080 vs 1024x768). 
I have form and inherited uc size 1300x950.

Comment: Still works correctly, and in both Vista and XP environments.  You may want to try creating a completely new project, create new user controls with minimum implementations and see if you can reproduce the issue as resulting from base class and not some other implementation detail.

Comment: Maybe I found the problem...
When I set the Localizable property to True, my UC doesn't scale it's Size to lower resolution. I have a test project to demonstrate this behaviour.